# Frama-C Windows Binary Available?

Tags: ocaml, frama-c

I am looking to do some experimenting with the Frama-C open source project and would like to install the tools on a Windows 7 machine.  It looks like previous versions have binary installers for Windows, but the latest version, Nitrogen, only has the source code available.  The website for the project [frama-c.com](http://frama-c.com) says that these should be available but I don't see them on their download page.  Are binary installers available somewhere else?

Comment: Building the command-line version only requires a POSIXish environment and OCaml (version between 3.10.2 and 3.12.1). So if you already have MinGW installed, it should be as simple as installing a binary package for OCaml from http://caml.inria.fr/ and then compiling Frama-C from source. It's the GUI that is frustrating to compile and distribute.

Comment: Still not an answer, but Sylvain Nahas provides relatively detailed compilation instructions as part of this bug report: http://bts.frama-c.com/view.php?id=1087

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find [here](http://lists.gforge.inria.fr/pipermail/frama-c-discuss/2012-February/003040.html) instructions to install a binary version of Frama-C Nitrogen, the latest version as of this writing. It installs on top of the older version Boron, and upgrades it to Nitrogen.

Comment: After all this time, I'm finally getting around to installing, but I am having problems with the link to instruction that you have.  After performing all of the steps and doing the test of the install, I get an error: 
Fatal error: exception GdkPixbuf.GdkPixbufError(3, "Couldn't recognize the image
 file format for file 'C:\Frama-c-Nitrogen-20111001\share\frama-c/frama-c.ico'")"  This file is there so I'm not sure what the problem is.  I might try to install under MSYS.

Comment: I have the same problem on a very recent installation; for some reason, only WODI's lablgtk managed to avoid that. In any case, since this is just the program taskbar icon and has merely aesthetic purposes, you can safely erase the .ico file (and eventually the .gif file as well, if you have a problem with it also as I did) and run again, it will emit a warning but should work fine otherwise.